# Nginx set ssl for URLs

Tags: web, https, nginx, admin

Good day. I got nginx server and it runs https connections. 
For now all URLs run with https. All i need is - to exclude some URLs from https, so they could be accessed with simple http.
Here is my NGINX config file:

```
server {
       listen           80;
       server_name              my-fin.ru www.my-fin.ru;

        root         /usr/server/finance/abacus/webapp;

        location ~ ^/.+\.(eot|ttf|woff)$ {
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        }

        location ~ ^/.+\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|jar|png|js|css|txt|epf|svg)$ {
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

        location / {
               return                   301 https://my-fin.ru;
        }

}

server {
        listen          *:443;
        server_name     my-fin.ru;
        client_max_body_size 10m;
        gzip                    on;
        gzip_min_length 500;
        gzip_buffers    4 8k;
        gzip_types              text/plain text/xml application/xml application/x-javascript text/javascript text/css text/json application/json;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/finance.access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/finance.error.log;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate         /usr/server/myfin.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /usr/server/myfin.key;
        charset                 utf-8;

        root         /usr/server/finance/abacus/webapp;

        location ~ ^/.+\.(eot|ttf|woff)$ {
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        }

        location ~ ^/.+\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|jar|png|js|css|txt|epf|svg)$ {
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

        location / {
                # give site more time to respond
                proxy_read_timeout 120;
                proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:8087;
                proxy_redirect          http:// $scheme://;

                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr ;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for ;
        }

}
```

Please help to configure  nginx.

Comment: so you want some URLs to be redirected to non-SSL if it was accessed by SSL correct?

Comment: Thats right. I need it.

Comment: Ok, which URL's are supposed to be non-SSL ?

Comment: http://domain/features, http://domain/info,http://domain/help/**

Comment: Also i got a web-app running locally on 8087 port, and one more app running locally on 8088 port. And i need the second of them (8088) run under https and be ablo by subdomain https://admin.domain/**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210047/nginx-set-ssl-for-urls?noredirect=1#comment24965146_17210047), Here's how i would do it.

```
## non https server
server {
    #non ssl server
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /path/to/root;
    location /features {
        #handle /features
    }
    location /info {
        # handle /info
    }
    location /help {
        #handle /help
    }
    location /
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
}
## https server
server {
    # handle ssl
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com subdomain1.example.com;
    root /path/to/root;
    location ~ /(features|help|info) {
        # redirect those 3 subfolders to http
        return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;
    }
    location / {
        #handle ssl requests;
    }
}
## https subdomain
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name subdomain2.example.com;
    root /path/to/root;
    location ~ /(features|help|info) {
        # redirect those 3 subfolders to http
        return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;
    }
    location / {
        # subdomain handling
    }
}
```

Please note that https wont work on subdomains unless you have a wildcard SSL certificate, otherwise the browser will issue a warning.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work. And could you help me with other task (another comment), so i could hadle subdomain requests.

Comment: you can always create another server block for the subdomain, if it has any different config, otherwise add it to the `server_name` separated by space, ill edit my answer to show u how.